# CSRF verification failed. Request aborted

Tags: nginx, django-admin, csrf, csrf-token

The only help towards this I can get is

It was working all day and all of a sudden this error starting popping up.

> "Reason given for failure: CSRF cookie not set."

Turning debug to TRUE gives me nothing more. I see no errors in nginx either.

I have set CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS

DEBUG = False

CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS = ['http://.*', 'http://example.com', 'http://example.com']

**HTTPS Settings**

SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE = True

CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE = False

SECURE_SSL_REDIRECT = False

**HSTS Settings**

SECURE_HSTS_SECONDS = 31536000

SECURE_HSTS_PRELOAD = True

SECURE_HSTS_INCLUDE_SUBDOMAINS = True

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FIXED:

I checked gunicorn status using:

```
 sudo systemctl status gunicorn
```

It gave me an error regarding my IP address needed adding to allowed hosts.

If error still persists:

```
sudo systemctl restart gunicorn
```